# C# MVC Model Data Group on Razor View

Tags: c#, linq, razor, model-view-controller

I'm having a bit of an issue on how to handle a model with duplicate data where I want to display each entry in a single table row in the view.

e.g.

The Model data looks like:

```
User | Access  
1234 | SuperUser  
1234 | Admin  
2345 | Analyst  
3456 | Analyst  
3456 | SuperUser
```

I pass through the model to my view but looping over each user in the model gives multiple entries per user, is there a way to use GroupBy to display each user on a single row, like the following:

```
User | Access  
1234 | SuperUser, Admin  
2345 | Analyst  
3456 | Analyst, SuperUser
```

Comment: Can you specify what the model actually looks like? E.g. is it a List<UserAccess> objects, with UserAccess having the fields "User" and "Access"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better if you can use Linq 
here the Example

create a new View Model Class

```
 public class MyNewView
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Access  { get; set; }
    }
```

in your view Controller add this Linq 
"mylist is your duplicate vaue list "

```
var NewViewModel =  mylist .select ( c=> new MyNewView {   

   user = c.user ,
   Access = String.Join(",",mylist.where( x=> x.user ==  c.user) .select( x => x Access ) .tolist() )    


} ).tolist()
```

then

```
return View(NewViewModel);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data structure class has 2 properties like this

```
public class YourClass
{
    public int User { set; get; }
    public string Access { set; get; }
}
```

You can do a group by on the `User` property of your object. You can use the LINQ `GroupBy` method and in the projection part of your LINQ expression, use `string.Join` to create the comma separate list value for Access property value

```
var flatRecords = new List<YourClass>
{
    new YourClass () {User = 1234, Access = "SuperUser"},
    new YourClass () {User = 1234, Access = "Admin"},
    new YourClass () {User = 33456,Access = "Analyst"}
};

List<YourClass> grouped = flatRecords.GroupBy(a => a.User, d => d,
                                               (k, v) => 
           new YourClass {   User = k, 
                             Access = string.Join(",", v.Select(d => d.Access)) 
                         })
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, how would the LINQ need to change if I had another couple of properties in the model (ID & LOGIN) but I dont want to display them on the view.

Comment: Whatever properties you are mapping in the projection part of the LINQ statement will be set in the result set. So if you do not want `ID` and `LOGIN` , do not set that. If it is MVC, i strongly suggest you to create a view model and use that in projection ( you can use the `YourClass` i have in the question). You cannot use the  EF entity classes in LINQ projection i believe.